# Redirection issue with wordpress blog directory URL's

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My blog is hosted at blog.example.com. I have a reverse proxy set up on my primary site such that request to www.example.com/blog will be served from blog.example.com.

request https://www.example.com/blog/wp-login.php is working properly, but all the wp-admin and wp-content URL are getting redirected without "blog" in the URL.

Example:

Requests to https://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/plugins.php redirects to https://www.example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php.

Kindly guide me in resolving the issue.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please write you `.htaccess`

Comment: @NikitaDudarev updated the question with .htaccess. Kindly look into it.

Comment: hmmm, it's so interesting, because your `RewriteBase` correct. You doesn't have const in `wp-config`, like `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');` ?

Comment: @NikitaDudarev No, I don't have any constant.

Comment: The interesting thing is wp-login.php working fine without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open phpmyadmin 
Check `wp_options` table

update `option_name`

```
siteurl => https://www.example.com/blog/

home =>  https://www.example.com/blog/
```